# Как перенести данные с PostgreSQL на SQLite

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite

У меня есть очень много данных пользователей и я хочу их сохранять и как мне это делать если все данные у меня на бд PostgreSQL в Django

А с помощью `python manage.py dumpdata` мне не подходит т.к там проблемы с кодировками

Для меня оптимальным решением была бы возможность переноса данных c Postgresql в sqlite

Я сейчас так и делаю но это рутинная работа которая отнимает время
Как мне сделать это простым и удобным способом

Comment: Что за проблема с "кодеками" ? Вы имеете в виду кодировку? Так может ее решить и не надо придумывать велосипед?
А вообще всегда можно написать скрипт, который будет брать данные из одной базы и сохранять их в другую.

Comment: @newman да я имел ввиду кодировку дело в том что у меня пользователи тг и у многих в био или именах какие-то непонятные символы и их django при команде ```loaddata``` не принимает в исходном виде

Comment: Пробовали добавить опцию, чтоб дамп делался в юникоде `python -Xutf8 manage.py dumpdata` ?